# 16 by 2 lcd display is not showing any character

Tags: lcd

I am trying to interface 16by2 lcd with msp432p401m controller but my 16 by 2 lcd is not showing any character. I have attached schematic and code for reference. By using same schematic and code 20 by 4 lcd is working properly.

please help me...

[image]

[image]

Comment: why do you believe that the same code would work for both displays? ... what is your question? ... you did not ask any

Comment: Do you realize that the MSP432P401M is not a 5V device and might not be able to interface reliably with a 5V device like your LCD? Do you get anything on the screen (for example: dark rectangles)? Your schematic does not show E, RS, 5V and GND connected to the display. Are they connected? Have you tried to adjust the contrast?

Comment: Your use of `(P4OUT & 0x00) |` seems pointless but harmless.  Otherwise nothing really jumps out that's worth mentioning.

Comment: @StarCat, `EN` and `RS` are labeled nodes at both the MCU and display. They're logically connected despite not having a graphic line running from one to the other.  Similar thing going on with `DGND` and `5VD`; somewhere else in the schematic they're more than likely labeled at a regulator. They've hardwired `RW` at LCD pin 5 into write mode.  Voting up with regard to other parts of your comment though.  All that said, *hopefully the backlight has some current limiting on the module*; I don't know that they all do.

Comment: @timemage, I mentioned EN and RS because they were not explicitly connected in the schematic and the question is clearly by someone inexperienced with this kind of material. There was a lot of information missing about the physical setup and I addressed some of that.